# how to Selecting XtraTab via C# Code

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am making 2 XtraTab in my `DetailGridControl`, I want to do something like this :

```
if( XtraTab1 is selected ) 
{ 
   code ...
}
else if ( XtraTab2 is selected ) 
{ 
   code ... 
}
```

But I don't know how can I select the XtraTab in the IF statement .

Comment: please add more info in your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be another way of accomplishing this, but the simplest and most effective way (without dwimmery or casting) I have found of both selecting a tab page and checking to see what tab page is selected is to use the `SelectedTabPageIndex` property of the tab control:

```
xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPageIndex = 2
```

Selects the third tab.

```
if (xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPageIndex == 0)
```

Checks to see if the first tab is the selected one or not.

Based on your construct, a `switch` statement would work nicely.